# What is the largest value a long data type can hold

Tags: vb.net, long-integer

I believe this question is sort of open ended, but I am seriously struggling. I keep getting an over flow.

I have two longs. The first is set to 16552800. I can add 32760 to it no problem. However I get an overflow error when I add 32820 to is.

Any ideas?!?!?!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [long in Visual Basic 6](http://www.rentron.com/datatypes.htm) is 32 bits and has a range from 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. You are nowhere near this limit. In VB.NET it is 64 bit.

It seems that you get an error when you add a number greater than or equal to 2<sup>15</sup> = 32768. Could you try 32767 and 32768 and see if that is the point at which the error starts occurring?

Are you sure that the overflow is coming from the addition? I suspect that you are trying to assign 32820 to a signed integer (range -32768 to +32767), and it's this assignment that gives the overflow, not the addition.